# Como eliminar el arranque grub?

Tags: linux

Tengo el arranque dual (grub) donde tengo windows8.1 y Kali linux, quiero formatear todo el disco y instalar solo kali linux. No se cual es la forma mas segura de quitar el arranque, formatear e instalar solo kali.

Comment: Sí formatea todo el disco, se perderán ambos sistemas operativos y su información. No existe forma "segura"  , solo formatee e instale nuevamente su distribución de Kali Linux. _(Teniendo en consideración hacer Backup de sus datos , claro está)_

Comment: Como dice el compañero Joel, si formateas **TODO** el disco se eliminará toda la información, a experiencia propia lo que hago es hacer una nueva partición en donde guarde toda mi información, tanto de windows como de linux y luego formatear y eliminar las particiones que no necesite, para que ahi instales Kali. Mucho ojo con la particion donde guardas tu info de no eliminarla, considera tambien hacer un respaldo aparte por si acaso.

Comment: @Dev.Joel Si, igual la info ya la tengo en un disco portable externo. Lo que me refiero es como formatear todo el disco? primero lo booteo para arrancar desde el cd de kali y desde ahi puedo colocar el formato de fichero para kali? soy noob en esto.

Comment: @Juanzu Sí , se formatea normal desde Kali y ahí mismo se le da el formato adecuado para el sistema. Lo primero que debería buscar en **google** es pasos para instalar Kali Linux.